# How I use the Enter Key on the Keyboard for my Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, keyboard

I have a ASP.NET Application and the User can input a string in a Textbox. If the User click on the button "send", the program search to this string in the Active Directoy. I want if I click Enter on my keyboard that the same Event activate how the "send" Button Event.

My cs code for this button:

```
 protected void btnBenutzerSuchen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //.... the code if I click Button "send"

        }
```

My ASPX:

```
<th><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Suchen" 
                                onclick="btnBenutzerSuchen_Click" Width="250" /></th>
```

what can I do?

tarasov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the defaultbutton to do the above.

```
<form runat="server" defaultbutton="myButton">
...
</form>
```

And then have a definition for the button.

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(myButton.Text);
}
```

So applying that for your code, you get something like this:

```
protected void btnBenutzerSuchen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //.... the code if I click Button "send"

    }
```

Your ASPX:

```
<th><asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button2">

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Suchen" OnClick="btnBenutzerSuchen_Click" Width="250" />

</asp:Panel></th>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property on Panel and HtmlForm controls which You can set to Your button ID.

Answer (score 1):

If u dont have any panels/div's Do this

On Page Load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
tbx_Find.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event,'" + btn_Find.ClientID + "')");
}
```

And In Javascript

```
function clickButton(e, buttonid){ 

  var evt = e ? e : window.event;

  var bt = document.getElementById("<%=btn_Find.ClientID %>");

  if (bt){ 

      if (evt.keyCode == 13){ 

            bt.click(); 

            return false; 

      } 

  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Javascript

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
    function doClick(buttonName,e)
    {
        var key;

         if(window.event)
              key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
         else
              key = e.which;     //firefox

        if (key == 13)
        {
            var btn = document.getElementById(buttonName);
            if (btn != null)
            { //If we find the button click it
                btn.click();
                event.keyCode = 0
            }
        }
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

in code behind

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   txtboxFirstName.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "doClick('" + btnSearch.ClientID + "',event)");

}
```